# Compass, config.rb and getting the output actually :compressed

Tags: compression, sass, compass-sass

This is my config.rb

```
preferred_syntax = :sass
http_path = '/'
css_dir = 'css'
sass_dir = 'sass'
images_dir = 'assets/images'
javascripts_dir = 'js'
relative_assets = true
line_comments = false
output_style = :compressed
```

The thing is that the code won't be compressed, sample of few blocks:

```
/* line 37, ../sass/style.scss */
.ui-state-highlight a, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight a, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight a {
  color: #363636;
}

/* line 37, ../sass/style.scss */
.ui-state-error, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-error, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-error {
  border: 1px solid #cd0a0a;
  background: #fef1ec url(images/ui-bg_glass_95_fef1ec_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
  color: #cd0a0a;
}

/* line 37, ../sass/style.scss */
.ui-state-error a, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-error a, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-error a {
  color: #cd0a0a;
}

/* line 37, ../sass/style.scss */
.ui-state-error-text, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-error-text, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-error-text {
  color: #cd0a0a;
}

/* line 37, ../sass/style.scss */
.ui-priority-primary, .ui-widget-content .ui-priority-primary, .ui-widget-header .ui-priority-primary {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* line 37, ../sass/style.scss */
.ui-priority-secondary, .ui-widget-content .ui-priority-secondary, .ui-widget-header .ui-priority-secondary {
  opacity: .7;
  filter: Alpha(Opacity=70);
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: Have you stopped and restarted your watch command since you've last modified the config.rb and forced it to recompile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config.rb is only read when the `compass` command is run.  If you're using `compass watch`, you will need to stop and start it before the changes will take effect.  You may also need to force it to recompile by making a minor change to one of your Sass files.