# Sass adds comments indicating line of the definition

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I"m not sure what's happening, but when I save my file and it is generated by compass I get comment above each declaration indicating which line of the sass file it is i.e:

```
/* line 55, ../sass/app.scss */
```

Also - in the config.rb I have

```
output_style = :compressed
```

but the output is expanded.

Any idea what might be causing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If compass is already running while you're modifying your config.rb file, you have to restart Compass to execute the changes.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19797651/2670516

> The config.rb is only read when the compass command is run. If you're
>   using compass watch, you will need to stop and start it before the
>   changes will take effect. You may also need to force it to recompile
>   by making a minor change to one of your Sass files.

If you just want to remove the comments then you can use:

```
line_comments = false
```

Hope it helps.